# Using Samba to share a folder from a Linux guest with a Linux host in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-shares

I have a VirtualBox vm (Slackware 13.1) which runs a samba share. I just moved that vm from a Windows 7 host to a Linux host (Slackware 14.1).

But now I cannot reach the share anymore. Why?

That's the only vm running on the host. The vm uses NAT and port forwarding is the same as it was in the Windows host:

```
137 > 137
138 > 138
139 > 139
445 > 445
```

Should I change something on the host?

I'm not sure the ports are properly forwarded, since I got the following from `nmap` on the host:

```
root@machine:/home/vboxuser# nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-15 09:26 BRT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000039s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
37/tcp   open  time
80/tcp   open  http
113/tcp  open  ident
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1
3306/tcp open  mysql
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=6.40%E=4%D=6/15%OT=22%CT=1%CU=40410%PV=N%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=5761497
OS:2%P=i486-slackware-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=106%GCD=1%ISR=108%TI=Z%CI=I%II=I%TS=
OS:A)OPS(O1=MFFD7ST11NW7%O2=MFFD7ST11NW7%O3=MFFD7NNT11NW7%O4=MFFD7ST11NW7%O
OS:5=MFFD7ST11NW7%O6=MFFD7ST11)WIN(W1=AAAA%W2=AAAA%W3=AAAA%W4=AAAA%W5=AAAA%
OS:W6=AAAA)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=AAAA%O=MFFD7NNSNW7%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%
OS:S=O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%
OS:RD=0%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W
OS:=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
OS:U1(R=Y%DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%D
OS:FI=N%T=40%CD=S)

Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.06 seconds
```

I was expecting `nmap` to show  137, 138, 139, 445. Why they are not appearing?

On the guest I see:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
37/tcp  open  time
113/tcp open  auth
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
```

And this:

```
# netstat -ntlup | grep smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1595/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1595/smbd
```

And for `nmbd`:

```
# netstat -ntlup | grep nmbd
udp        0      0 10.0.2.255:137          0.0.0.0:*                           1600/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:137           0.0.0.0:*                           1600/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           1600/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.0.2.255:138          0.0.0.0:*                           1600/nmbd
udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:138           0.0.0.0:*                           1600/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           1600/nmbd
```

Comment: Confirm that samba isn't binding to 127.0.0.1 (`netstat -ntlup | grep smbd` ), and that it is allowed by your firewall. Samba is installed, and your smb.conf is being loaded right? does `testparm -s` show anything? Anyway NAT problems are always one of the Three P's; Process running, Port established on accessible IP, and Path between the source and dest IPs. so confirm that smbd is running, listening on 0.0.0.0 or the box IP, and isn't being blocked by a firewall between IPs.

Comment: Question edited. Does the `netstat`  seems ok?

Comment: `:::*` is Ipv6 for `0.0.0.0`, so thats good. I assume you are using IPv6 only? otherwise there is a problem with samba binding to IPv4. are there entries for UDP\137,138 if you switch `smbd` to `nmbd`? if so, and you can connect to samba locally, then the issue is firewall or NAT. You could always put the connection in bridged mode, set a static IP in the lan range, and confirm that everything is working, if you want to eliminate NAT as a potential issue.

Comment: Question edited. Does the netstat seems ok for nmbd? I'll say I prefer IPV4, IPV6 seems strange for me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you say something about the difference between `:::*` and `0.0.0.0:*` shown in return of `smbd` and `nmbd`? Is it ok? Locally I can acccess the shares via Dolphin. Since there is no firewall in Slackware I guess that's not the issue.

Comment: ok, I've never seen anything like that. smbd is running on IPv6 only, and nmbd is running on IPv4 only. I'm going to guess that your interface bindings in smb.conf are not right, but I'm still not sure how you could do that even intentionally. Perhaps disabling IPv6 is the best next step.